# How can I just draw a specific sprite in a Group with pygame draw()?

Tags: python, pygame, draw

```
<Group(4 sprites)>
```

I have 4 sprites in a group they all ready to draw with the line,

```
stuff_to_draw.draw(screen)
```

They all currently draw at the same time.

Is it possible to do something like this

```
stuff_to_draw[0].draw(screen)
```

I've looked at [documentation for pygame Groups](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), but can not find any helpful information about selecting a specific element in the group.

**What am I trying to achieve?**

The sprite group currently holds a answer sprite which consists of a location (x,y) and a image of the letter to blit.

Currently across all maps the answer is blitted instead of on the current question. So I would like to be able to say on question one `stuff_to_draw[0]` then question two `stuff_to_draw[1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, add a `self.type` to your each of your sprites. Give it a value, such as `self.type = 1`.  Then call this when you want to draw a certain sprite or group of sprites:

```
for sprite in group: #Replace group with your sprite group
    if sprite.type == 1: #Or whatever type you want
        sprite.draw(screen)
    elif sprite.type == 2:
        sprite.draw(screen)
    #Etc...
```

Next, in your `sprite` class make sure you inherit from `pygame.sprite.Sprite`:

```
class my_sprite_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__()
        #Etc...

    #Add this draw function so we can draw individual sprites
    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I forgot that individual sprites don't have a draw function, just the groups. @pmoleri @jackdh my bad

Please read this [post](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) here to get an idea of what the class can do.

If you have any more questions just comment below.

Comment: Sprite.draw() doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes it does, if you're using `pygame.sprite.Sprite`.  You usually use `pygame.sprite.Sprite` with pygame's sprite Groups.  And please don't downvote an answer because it isn't yours.  Thank you :)

Comment: Hi I tried this, and I pass it correctly as seen gist.github.com/jackdh/58732728834f2b8f7338 although I get a error. gist.github.com/jackdh/a398887c329ec7fb9aaa Any idea why?

Comment: @Remolten it doesn't: `pygame.sprite.Sprite().draw(None)` gives: `'Sprite' object has no attribute 'draw'`. And your assumption of me downvoting because it isn't my answer, is really far from true.

Comment: Please read my new edited post above.  It should work.  @pmoleri no offense intended bro :)

Comment: @Remolten I read the updated post but it still doesn't have a draw() method. If you want one you need to implement it in `my_sprite_class`.

Comment: Please read the link.  When you subclass `pygame.sprite.Sprite` you are making `my_sprite_class` a "child" of it.  That mean it inherits all of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite` class' functions etc.  One of these is the `draw(screen)` function.

Comment: I've tried using your edited version although It still gives me the errors Enzone has no attribute draw. https://gist.github.com/jackdh/ee17a9042604e5c4dd33 Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: My bad guys, didn't write my answer correctly.  Should work now I hope.

Answer (score 2):

You could blit any individual sprite, but I don't recommend it. This would be the way:

```
sprite = stuff_to_draw.sprites()[0]
screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)
```

My recommendation is to keep in the Sprites Group what you want to draw at a moment, and keep the rest in a separate list or group.

Comment: Why would you not recommend it? Would you mind showing me how I would do it anyway for educational purposes?

Comment: Because Sprites Groups are meant for drawing all its elements, and some advanced groups (ex: RenderUpdates) can even keep track of every updated area to make optimizations in the update of the screen.